# Doing a count along with distinct to check number of times a post was read

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table in Mysql which i use to collect data for the number of times a users views a post. reader_id is the id of the user reading the post, read_pub_id is the id of the person who published/wrote the post and read_artc_id is the post's id.

Its create is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `reads_t` (
    `reader_id` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `read_pub_id` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `read_artc_id` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`reader_id`, `read_pub_id`, `read_artc_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Then I use a Insert Ignore statement each time a post is read, like this:

```
insert ignore into reads_t (reader_id, read_pub_id, read_artc_id) values (3,2,1);
```

So I end up with data like this:

```
reader_id; read_pub_id; read_artc_id
        1;           1;           1
        1;           1;           2
        1;           1;           3
        2;           1;           1
        2;           1;           2
        2;           1;           3
        2;           2;           2
        2;           2;           3
        3;           1;           1
        3;           2;           1
        3;           2;           2
```

Here, user 1 read publisher 1's article 1 and so on.

How do i do the sql so I can end up with data like this: It's the total times a post by a publisher was read by a reader. I'll later use this to update the 'read' column for each post.

```
read_pub_id ; read_artc_id ; times_read
          1              1            3
          1              2            2
          1              3            2
          2              1            1
          2              2            2
          2              3            1
```

I can see this can't be done in a simple select statement that I'm used to. I tried the one below, but that gives me strange results.

```
select read_pub_id, read_artc_id, count(read_artc_id) as times_read from reads_t;
```

Comment: what if you add GROUP BY read_pub_id, read_artc_id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the GROUP BY clause, like this:

```
SELECT
  read_pub_id,
  read_artc_id,
  count(read_artc_id) as times_read
FROM
  reads_t
GROUP BY
  read_pub_id,
  read_artc_id;
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Like @fthiell suggested, you were very close :), you should use something like:

```
select read_pub_id, read_artc_id, count(read_artc_id) as times_read
from reads_t
group by read_pub_id, read_artc_id;
```