# Doing a select and update inside a Mysql event

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing a select inside a mysql event, and then trying to update another table with data from that select. But it does not seem to be working.

I'm doing:

```
BEGIN
select read_pub_id, read_artc_id, count(read_artc_id) as times_read from reads_t GROUP BY read_pub_id, read_artc_id;
update reads_totals set read_total = times_read where pub_id = read_pub_id and artc_id = read_artc_id;
update reads_totals set ts=now(); /*This is for testing*/
END
```

Only the ts gets updated. Which means the event is working.

Is there a while loop to be added in here, and how? Whats the right way to do this?

My previous question relating to this is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110393/doing-a-count-along-with-distinct-to-check-number-of-times-a-post-was-read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select read_pub_id, read_artc_id, count(read_artc_id) as times_read from reads_t 
 GROUP BY read_pub_id, read_artc_id;
 update reads_totals
 set read_total = (select count(read_artc_id) from reads_t rt 
 where pub_id = rt.read_pub_id 
 and artc_id = rt.read_artc_id);
```

Comment: So if I do it like this I don't need to use the select statement in there?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean:

```
UPDATE reads_totals T
SET read_total = (SELECT count(read_artc_id) 
                  FROM reads_t R 
                  WHERE R.read_pub_id = T.pub_id 
                  AND R.read_artc_id = T.artc_id);
```

This query though will update *every row* in `reads_totals`, I'm not sure this is really what you intend.

Comment: That's right. Every row for that author and post need to get updated.